# How to support XMLRPC bindings in WCF .Net 4 web service without tinyblogger example

Tags: wcf, xml-rpc

Darin Dimitrov answered a question about supporting XMLRPC interface (bindings) under a WCF .net web service. In his response, he explained to add references to Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc and TinyBlogEngine.

Why is the TinyBlogEngine engine needed?
How can I take a working .net 4 WCF web service and add support for XMLRPC without making it a blog application?

Comment: Please show a link where Darin said this.

Comment: I guess I could have been more detailed in my post. Thank you for asking for the link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097020/configuring-xml-rpc-behavior-for-iis-hosted-svc-file

Comment: I am using .net 4. Should I be able to support xmlrpc client by adding endpoint addresses? would basicHttpBinding all that I need to have? Why is Microsoft.Samples.xmlrpc needed? Does .net 4 still need Microsoft.Samples.xmlrpc?

Comment: From additional reading, it seems that WCF does not support the XMLRPC protocol so Microsoft.Samples.xmlrpc is still needed. I am still not about to find a way to use this Microsoft component to add support to a WCF .net web service. All help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the TinyBlogEngine engine needed?

`TinyBlogEngine` simply contains the WCF web service code which you could replace with any implementation you like (blog or whatever). This could be an existing web service you already have. `Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc` is what enables a XML RPC binding to an existing WCF service. You just need to have this [`XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorExtension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097020/configuring-xml-rpc-behavior-for-iis-hosted-svc-file) I've shown in the post if you want to be able to configure the RPC binding via web.config.

Comment: Thank you Mr Dimitrov. I needed that to know I was on the right track. Config file had a few problems and it is working now. XMLRPC calls come into my wcf .net web service now. I did find that you cannot use the devstudio's local web server to take calls. You need to let your IIS service do that but you can still debug the code.