# WCF + Xml-Rpc don't work

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, xml-rpc

I have a classic WCF webservice. Few weeks ago, in order to answer to a client demand, I added Rest management to my webservice.

But, at the beginning of the week, another client said to me its system can only manage XML-RPC. So he needs to connect to my webservice via this protocol.

So I found this : [Configuring XML-RPC behavior for IIS-hosted .SVC file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097020/configuring-xml-rpc-behavior-for-iis-hosted-svc-file)

First, I compiled the Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc in order to add it to my project. Two Dll appears : Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc & Microsoft.ServiceModel.XmlRpc

Then, I created a XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorExtension class, the same as the post above :

```
namespace WsZendesk
{
    public class XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            // this comes from Microsoft.Samples.XmlRpc
            return new XmlRpcEndpointBehavior();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(XmlRpcEndpointBehavior); }
        }
    }
}
```

After, I created my interface for Xml-Rpc :

```
namespace WsZendesk
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWsZendeskRpc
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "wszendesk.GetUserIdFromBarcode")]
        void GetUserIdFromBarcode(String sXmlIn, out String sXmlOut);
    }
}
```

Finaly, I modified my web.config in order to allow RPC :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WsZendesk.WsZendesk" behaviorConfiguration="WsZendeskServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="RESTEndPoint"
          contract="WsZendesk.IWsZendeskRest" />
        <endpoint address="xmlrpc" behaviorConfiguration="xmlRpcBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="RPCEndPoint"
          contract="WsZendesk.IWsZendeskRpc" />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="SOAPEndPoint"
          contract="WsZendesk.IWsZendesk" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="xmlRpc"
             type="WsZendesk.XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorElement, WsZendesk" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="xmlRpcBehavior">
          <xmlRpc />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsZendeskServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Visual Studio said he don't know the child element 'xmlRpc'. So, when I try to launch my webservice, the same error appears during the execution.

[image: error in Visual Studio]

[image: error during execution]

Anybody can help me to use Xml-Rpc with my existing webservice ?

For information, my project is in C# 4.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Exactly what is the error that "appears"? Where does it "appear"? Do you mean that you get an exception? Then please post the complete exception.

Comment: @John : Sorry about that. It will no appear anymore. I will edit my post with screenshots

Comment: Je ne parle pas français, mais il semble que signifie cette exception que la classe ne peut pas être instanciée. Est-ce exact? (I don't speak French, but it looks like that exception means that the class cannot be instantiated. Is that correct?, and since this is an English-only site, it's best to not require us to use Google mis-Translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not this:

```
<add name="xmlRpc"
type="WsZendesk.XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorElement, WsZendesk" />
```

But this:

```
<add name="xmlRpc"
             type="WsZendesk.XmlRpcEndpointBehaviorExtension, WsZendesk" />
```